# I want to make a line under the text in my table

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a border/frame under the text as same as the photo below

[image]

```css
      table.blueTable {
      background-color: #5F80A8;
      height: 200px;
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      bottom: -165px;
      color: white;
    }

    table.blueTable td {
      font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    #uno,
    #tre,

    {
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 4em;
    }

    #due,
    #quattro,

    {
      text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">

    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>table6</title>
      <table class="blueTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td id="uno">初期費用</td>
    <td id="due">15万～30万<br>（選択プランによる</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="tre">月額費用</td>
    <td id="quattro">5万～15万<br>（選択プランによる）<br>＋SMS送信料 12円/通<br>＋IVR利用料　8円/60秒</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add css for table border as below:

```
    td, th {
border: solid 1px;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
}
```

Here is your updated code:

```css
      table.blueTable {
      background-color: #5F80A8;
      height: 200px;
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      bottom: -165px;
      color: white;
    }
 
    td, th {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
} 

    table.blueTable td {
      font-size: 1.3em;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    #uno,
    #tre,

    {
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 4em;
    }

    #due,
    #quattro,

    {
      text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">

    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>table6</title>
      <table class="blueTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td id="uno">初期費用</td>
    <td id="due">15万～30万<br>（選択プランによる</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="tre">月額費用</td>
    <td id="quattro">5万～15万<br>（選択プランによる）<br>＋SMS送信料 12円/通<br>＋IVR利用料　8円/60秒</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thank you but I did that before and the final result is not as same as the picture

Comment: @Pestacarne That is because the text in your source is not the same as the text in the screenshot of what you want. Also, increase the border-spacing.

Comment: the text family font or the text size?

Comment: I have changed the font size,the font-family and the text but the result is still the same

Comment: @Mr lister YES!!! it worked great I have added border-spacing: xx px; to my code and the table and now displays exactly as the screenshot Thank you very much!!!


}

Answer (score 0):

Can you add cellspacing to your table tag. Hope this will solve the issue.

```
 <table class="blueTable" cellspacing="30">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

table.blueTable td {
 font-size: 1.3em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 }
```

Comment: I gave  it already     table.blueTable td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}   and   table.blueTable td {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}     but unfortunately the final result is not the same as the picture,thank you

Comment: Are you using it with some other code? If so can you share the js fiddle code here. Let me check something overwrites your table style or not?

Comment: can you please add cellspacing to your table tag

Comment: Yes I just added border-spacing: 20px; to my table and now it displays properly,thank you!

Comment: I have another issue please,actually the {article 2} is over/covering the table and it does not look good so I want to put it just below  the "mobile phone and two servers" photo,how can I do that?      https://jsfiddle.net/Pestacarne/4d9b0o61/

Comment: .table, table for this remove "bottom: -100px;"

Comment: if this solves your issue please close the question.

Comment: I have removed  {bottom : -100px;}  from .table,table but unfortunately it did not solve my issue